# Excel formula for variable fields

Tags: excel, variables, http-headers, for-loop, formula

I am looking for a simple formula to do the calculation on two fields that are variable,
for e.g., c1 has 100 and c3 has 150 and I want to calculate an increase/decrease percentage, but the trick is the cell values change every month.  How do I put the formula to cater for such variation.

Appreciate your help.

Regards

Comment: Do you want the change percentage between c1 and c3, or between c1's value now and c1's value after it eventually changes?

Comment: I just want the percentage cell to display the correct percentage whenever the values in either c1 or c3 changes whether c1 is greater than c3 or smaller.

Comment: If C1 goes from 100 to 200 in the next month, are you saying you need to remember the value (or percentage) for the month prior?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, I'm missing something, but taking your question literally, the answer is the following formula

```
=(C3-C1)/C3
```

You can format the cell containing this formula as a percentage if required.